# How can I make my function run in constant time?

Tags: java, performance

I just received back my assignment and I lost marks for one function because it does not run at constant time, it wasn't efficient enough. I would have to go through the trouble of booking an appointment and waiting to get an answer from my prof, I was wondering if someone here could help me now.

I have a function that removes and returns randomly an item from an ArrayList.

```
public T pick() {
    int end = l.size() - 5;
    if (l.size() == 0)
        return null;
    assert(next >= 2 && next <= l.size()-1);
    T x = l.remove(next);
    next = (l.size() > 0) ? r.nextInt(l.size()) : -5;
    return x;
}
```

Could someone point out what I can do to make this code more efficient? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Define more efficient? Is this running excruciatingly slow?

Comment: @Thihara "Efficient" was quite clearly defined in the question. user, we need more information about your use case. Generally speaking, you can't return a "random" item from a queue; that's the point of using a queue. If you are wanting to return a random item from the middle of a list, the list implementation is critical.

Comment: The running time of this method depends on what `T` is... Most probably `remove()` is not O(1). Also, "random" and "queue" don't really fit together.

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant an ArrayList, not queue. My bad.

Comment: I suggest you tell us *what the function is supposed to do.* Without that information, assistance is impossible. Also provide the missing declarations, e.g. of `next.` And whether use of an `ArrayList` was specified in the question. The question, in fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `ArrayList.remove` has linear time complexity, if `next` is not near to the end. The *trick* is to swap the element at position *next* with the *last* element, and remove the *last* element.

```
T x = l.get(next);
l.set(next, l.get(l.size() - 1));
l.remove(l.size() - 1);
```

Comment: How would I check if next is near to the end?

Comment: ...of,course this only applies if list is not in some specific order, like sorted. If it is, then some other container needs to be used, such as LinkedHashMap, or whatever fits the requirements not explained in the question.

Comment: It is not "ArrayList.remove has linear time complexity, if next is not near to the end.", it is "ArrayList.remove has linear time complexity, period".

Comment: @LieRyan: I agree that the wording "neat to the end" isn't good. However, it is important that `l.remove(l.size() - 1)` is a constant time operation on `ArrayList`.